# SIPML5 connection to Asterisk 13 over wss

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, wss

I have successfully setup sipml5 using a standard non secure ws:// to an asterisk 13 server, can make and receive calls using demo at https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/call.htm.  However, I am having problem with wss or secure socket connection.

**I got this error (chrome):**

WebSocket connection to 'wss://myserver.com:8089/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

**My settings**

WebSocket Server URL -> wss://myserver.com:8089/ws

SIP outbound Proxy URL -> udp://myserver.com:5060

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved this problem by adding following line to http.conf

```
tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0:8089
tlscertfile=/path-to/cert.pem
tlsprivatekey=/path-to/privkey.pem
```

Comment: Note: the port 8089 should be open

Comment: Hi @Sibin John Mattappallil I am working on calling to asterisk server using sipml5 but I am getting failed to connect to server and checking the console I get below error , I would request you to please help me in guiding me in correct direction as I have been struggling on this since many days.Thanks in advance.

tsip_transport.js WebSocket connection to
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT